# How to pass timestamp from bash to psql

Tags: bash, timestamp, escaping, psql

I am having problem with passing timestamp parameter to psql. In `$since` variable I can have any string formatted according to SQL standard and I pass this value to sql like this:

First I check if `$since` is in correct format (if it fails it won't continue):
1) `psql --command "SELECT ($since)::TIMESTAMPTZ;"`

Second I use the value in my function (it takes timestamptz as input parameter):
2) `cmd="SELECT myfunc($since);"
psql --command "$cmd" $DBNAME`

**Works**: if `since="NOW() - INTERVAL '5 months'"`
**Does not work**: if `since="2017-10-23 10:42:48"` (it fails on LINE 1: SELECT (2017-10-23 10:42:48)::TIMESTAMPTZ; error)

I tried to escape the `$since` string somehow with ', ", \ characters, but after many combinations both in bash and sql I gave up.
What is the correct way to escape in such case?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to cast a **string** to TIMESTAMPTZ, so you need to enclose the value of $since in ' ', either when creating the variable

```
since="'2017-10-23 10:42:48'"
```

or when passing it to psql:

```
since="2017-10-23 10:42:48"
psql --command "SELECT '$since'::TIMESTAMPTZ ;"
```

If you need to pass **either a string or an expression** like `NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day'` you would better decide about the quoting when assigning the value to the variable, so:

```
$ since="'2017-10-23 10:42:48'"
$ psql postgres --command "SELECT $since::TIMESTAMPTZ ;"
      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2017-10-23 10:42:48+02
(1 row)
$ since="(NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day')"
$ psql postgres --command "SELECT $since::TIMESTAMPTZ ;"
          timestamptz          
-------------------------------
 2018-03-24 08:49:24.577356+01
(1 row)
```

Comment: But what if you have
since="'NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day''"
?